# Design by Contract

Tags: oop

I'm learning about [Design by Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) and I've stumbled upon this statement:

> Subclasses in an inheritance hierarchy are allowed to weaken
>   preconditions (but not strengthen them) and strengthen postconditions
>   and invariants (but not weaken them).

I'm not sure I fully grasp this. From what I've gathered, the preconditions of a method are the parameters passed into the function, whereas the postcondition is, for example, a guaranteed return type or some sort of assertion on the return type of a method.

Why exactly are subclasses allowed to weaken preconditions but must strengthen postconditions? Are these simply definitions in regards to the Liskov Substituation principle or is there some underlying logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preconditions are not the parameters, preconditions are expectations about parameters.  For example, a precondition might be that `param1` is never a null reference, while `param2` is allowed to be null.  `param3` might be an `IEnumerable`, but perhaps a precondition requires at least one item is returned from that enumerable.

Its ok to weaken preconditions, because a particular implementation won't break others; that is, it doesn't break other sub-classes if one of them says an empty enumerable is ok.

Likewise, post conditions are rules about the return value.  One common and useful post condition is that a null reference can never be returned.  A method with such a post condition means callers never need to worry about handling a null option.  Weakening a post condition is not allowed because all callers are never expecting null, and thus may break if they suddenly get null from an instance.

These rules are basically a restatement of the LSP, but Design by Contract is meant to make you think about the contract a method should have up front, as it can sometimes be an afterthought, if its a thought at all, when creating methods.